# Create a copy of any file the user inputs using fopen(fp,"wb")

Tags: c, fwrite, fread

The copy of the file has all the contents of the original and along with that something like "\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\". Also it gives error only for txt files other file formats get copied easily. I had tried using fread and fwrite earlier as well but then it wasn't giving any such problem. Is there something that I have tried wrong. It says that the file I've opened has some invalid characters in case it is a text file.

```
  char strr[1];
  int e;
  bzero(strr,1);
  while((e=(fread(strr,1,1,fpp)))>0)
  {
    fwrite(strr,1,1,bck);
    i++;
  }
  if(e>0)
  {
    fclose(bck);
  }
```

I think the problem lies in the above code.I am adding the entire code as well. Please don't comment on the multithreading part, I know it is useless when I m using mutex and when it won't reduce any time. There is a lot of work to be done. Please could you help me with the above problem. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
int counter;
static FILE * fpp;
static FILE * bck;
pthread_mutex_t lock;
int wc;
int flag;
int lent;
unsigned long fsize(char* file)
{
    FILE * f = fopen(file, "rb+");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    unsigned long len = (unsigned long)ftell(f);
    fclose(f);
    return len;
}
void* doSomeThing(void* arg)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  char str; 
  int i=0;
  counter++;
  char buff[100];
  bzero(buff,100);
  char strr[1];
  int e;
  bzero(strr,1);
  while(((e=(fread(strr,1,1,fpp)))>0) || i<=lent)  
  {
    fwrite(strr,1,1,bck);
    i++;
   }
   if(e>0)
   {
     fclose(bck);
   }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  return NULL;
}

int main()

{
  int i = 0;
  int err;

  char filn[100];
  printf("\nEnter Filename:");
  scanf("%s",filn);
  unsigned long len= fsize(filn);   
  lent=(int) len;
  lent=lent/5;
  printf("%lu",len);
  char backf[100];
  printf("\nEnter Filename to copy");
  scanf("%s",backf);
  bck=fopen(backf,"wb+");
  fpp=fopen(filn,"rb+");
  pthread_t tid[6];
  pthread_t * temp;
  fseek(fpp, 0, SEEK_SET);
  if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL)!=0)
  {
      printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
      return 1;
   }
  for(i=0;i<6;i++)
  err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
  //if (err != 0);
  int j=0;
  for(j=0;j<6;j++)
  {
    pthread_join(tid[j], NULL);
  }
  printf("\n%d",wc-1);    
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
  //fclose(bck);
  fclose(fpp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indentation was off at two lines earlier. It was because I was using emacs and gedit alternately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (e=(fread(strr,1,1,fpp)>0) )
```

has the brackets wrong. It should probably be

```
while ((e=fread(strr,1,1,fpp))>0)
```

Besides, your indentation is horrible, and reading/writing 1 byte at a time is very inefficient, and it's wrong to make the `fclose` dependent on the `if(e>0)`, but neither is the cause of your problem.

#### Brackets

fread returns the number of records read (in your case, number of bytes, as the record size is 1). It seems like you want to keep reading as long as you get a byte. But your `e=(fread..)>0` compares first, then assigns the result of the comparison to e. This is actually ok in this case, because fread can return either 1 or 0 in this specific case - and you want the loop to stop when the return value isn't 1. But generally, this is often a case of an error, because people want the return value in the variable. So your statement just doesn't *look* right.

#### Indentation

is fixed now.

#### read/write 1 byte at a time

is extremely slow, even with the buffering that fread/fwrite provide. Processing chunks of a decently sized buffer is much faster. How big the buffer should be depends on your hardware, but 4K or 8K is a good start to use. Of course, in your specific application, you probably want to give the thread something to do instead of just copying everything in one big chunk.

#### make fclose dependent on (anything)

is normally wrong unless (anything) == (fopen succeded). When you're finished with the file and don't want to use it anymore, you close it. Period.

In your case, you have a loop `while (e ... > 0)`, then an `if (e>0)` The part within the if condition will never get executed, as the if will never be reached with `e>0`. So you don't close your file anywhere. (Which, in this specific case, is a good thing, because later threads will still access it, but generally, is a mistake).

#### Threads

Your original post didn't mention the pthread stuff at all.

The way you use it, your first thread will perform the copy operation; while this is happening, the other threads get stuck in the mutex. After the 1st thread releases the mutex, one of the other threads will start trying to copy the file. At this point, the file pointer of the input file is at EOF, where the 1st thread left off; the next thread will try to read more data, fail, and write the un-modified, zero-initialized strr to the backup file. This repeats until the `i<lent` part becomes false. Same for all other threads. This is probably where your extra `\000` bytes come from. Btw. this shows how important it is to post everything. Your original post discarded the `i<lent` part, and said nothing about multiple threads, but these are exactly the key points that lead to your undesired result.

Comment: I don't know why geeks turn into Nazi's on seeing a newbie's code. Remember even you were a noob once.

Comment: Many people, including me, have no problem with newbies, and actually like to be helpful - otherwise we wouldn't answer SO questions. However, the less clear, concise, and easy-to-read a question is, the harder it is to answer. This means questions that lack information, are hard to read, or don't show effort on the side of the poster, are annoying to everybody who might answer. Code formatting isn't exactly rocket science, but your original post (which got edited in the meanwhile) was incomplete, and badly formatted. This is what made me answer in a harsher tone than i normally do.

Comment: It seems to me this is a good, thorough answer.  It picks the most important problem as the first one, and then discusses other problems in the code.  Good work, Guntram.  The only thing I'd probably do is use some level 3 headings (started by `###`) instead of the lettered sub-headings like `e) Threads`, to make it easier to read.  So, `### Threads`, for example.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your help Guntram. I figured out the silly errors earlier after reading the man page for fread and that it was a stupid question to ask on stackoverflow. I was going to remove it and then found your very elaborate response here. Thanks a tonne!